# Pair a bluetooth device in Mac OS Desktop application

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

I am developing a MAC desktop application and I have successfully collected the bluetooth devices in my range. Now I just one to pick one to pair it with me computer system's bluetooth device. I am not getting anything useful over google. Does any one has any idea of doing it? It will be great help for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array of CBPeripherals that you discovered, then literally you only need to call `connectPeripheral:options:` from your CBCentralManager and pass in one of the CBPeripherals.. Ensure you have set up your `CBCentralManagerDelegate` in order to get the `didConnectPeripheral:` callback.

All the info you need is right here:
[CBCentralManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/connectPeripheral%3aoptions%3a)